# strange mysql truncation warning with view + case + null check

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm getting a weird warning from a MySQL query when I use a combination of a view, a case statement, and a null check. I believe I have a minimal test case:

```
create table t (x char(1)) default charset 'utf8';

insert into t values ('a');

create or replace view v as select case when true then x end as y from t;

select y is null from v;

show warnings;
```

I see:

```
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'a  ' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

When I inline the view, remove the case statement, or remove the null check, the warning disappears.

Another baffling thing is that in the warning message, the string is right-padded to 3x its original length, no matter what we set that length to in the `create table` and `insert` statements. If I remove `default charset 'utf8'` from the `create table` statement, the right-padding goes away but the warning persists.

Note that this warning actually turns into an error in my use case, where I do the equivalent of the following:

```
create table t2 (x char(1)) default charset 'utf8';

insert into t2 select y is null from v;
```

I was unable to find a bug report about this issue and I assume it's not the intended behavior. I am using Server version: 5.6.11-56-log Percona Server (GPL), Release rc60.3, Revision 376. Can anyone explain why it's happening and/or suggest a workaround?

Comment: Gordon, on that page I see the following, indicating that "show warnings" isn't a valid query (it probably only works in a terminal): "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show warnings' at line 1".

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle . . . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f836c/1.  Add `insert into t2 select y is null from v` on the left and it will generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and will post it here in case anyone else has the same issue. Instead of this:

```
select y is null from v
```

Use this:

```
select y is null from (select y from v) as _
```

No idea why it works but it does.